# By what principle will it be correct to distribute queues in celery and rabbitmq?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, fastapi

I have a small pet project that is an api written in fastpic and using postgresql and sqlalchemyORM. Recently I came across such a thing as Celery and decided to add it to my project, but I ran into the problem that I don't understand a little on what principle it is best for my project to apply it.

Briefly about my project

This is a Restful Api for creating companies and employees within companies. The api has logic for 4 roles. I check what role the user has with the help of jwt tokens, and I store session data in radish.

Here is the tree of my project

```
├───alembic
├───auth
├───celery
├───crud_routs_func
│   ├───accounts_db_func
│   └───dash_board_func
├───db
│   ├───backup_folder
├───logger
├───rabbitmq
│   └───mnesia
├───routes
└───utils
```

In main.py I add all the routes from the routes folder.

```
def main():
    app.include_router(ManipulationEmployeesController.create_router())
    app.include_router(AccountController.create_router())
    app.include_router(AuthenticateController.create_router())
    app.include_router(CompanyController.create_router())
    app.include_router(SellingPointsController.create_router())
    app.include_router(InviteEmployeeController.create_router())
    app.include_router(CriteriesController.create_router())
    app.include_router(DashboardController.create_router())
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, ws_ping_interval=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_backup_job, args=())
    t1.start()
    main()
```

Every router I have looks something like this and receives data thanks to functions of a certain class to access the database.

```
class CompanyController(Controller):
    prefix = "/api/company"
    tags = ["company"]

    @post("/create")
    @check_access(["owner"])
    async def create(request: Request, item: schemas.Company):
        user = _T.user_items(request)
        CompanyDBFunc.create_company(ur_name=item.ur_name,true_name=item.true_name, 
                                    inn=item.inn, ur_address=item.ur_address,
                                    true_address=item.true_address, phone=item.phone, 
                                    email=item.email, owner_id=user["id"])
        response = JSONResponse(status_code=201, content={"message":"You have successfully created a company!"})
        return response

    @put("/update")
    @check_access(["owner"])
    async def update(request: Request, item: schemas.Company, company_id):
        user = _T.user_items(request)
        CompanyDBFunc.update_company(company_id, user['id'], ur_name=item.ur_name, true_name=item.true_address, inn=item.inn, ur_address= item.ur_address, 
                            true_address=item.true_address, phone=item.phone, email=item.email)
        response = JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message":"Company data has been successfully updated."})
        return response
```

This is about what any class looks like for me to access the database

```
class CompanyDBFunc(DbConnect):

    @classmethod    
    @Logger.log
    def create_company(self, ur_name, true_name, inn, ur_address, true_address, phone, email, owner_id):
        new_company = models.Company(ur_name=ur_name, true_name= true_name, inn=inn, ur_address=ur_address, true_address=true_address, phone=phone, email=email, owner_id=owner_id)
        self.session_work.add(new_company)
        self.session_work.commit()
        self.session_work.close()

    @classmethod
    @Logger.log
    def get_company_ids_by_owner_id(self, owner_id):
        company_ids = self.session_work.query(models.Company.id).filter_by(owner_id=owner_id).all()
        company_ids = [c[0] for c in company_ids]
        self.session_work.close()
        return company_ids
```

How to use celery correctly in such applications and by what logic should queues be created for processing ?

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Workqueues are a solution to the problem of "how do I coordinate/handle long running tasks / tasks that aren't dependent on being run right now" when my application is a web application and receives many, many requests. i.e. "I need to encode this video file to a new format, but the user shouldn't have to wait until that's done to get a response that the file has been uploaded" - you'd then move the long running task out to the queue and let the queue workers handle the encoding, while giving the user the relevant information about the request being added to the queue.

Comment: There is nothing in your description that seems to necessitate using a queue of any sort; but if you're allowing users to register themselves or reset their passwords, you could move that task to a queue instead of sending the confirmation email directly from your code for example.

Comment: That is, it will be bad practice if any access to the database gets into the queue ?

Comment: I wouldn't do that, no - that would really just add additional overhead to a common task. However, if you _do_ have some queries that take a long time to complete (for example complex reporting tasks), they would probably be better handled by a queue. But regular, run-of-the-mill db queries doesn't need that additional complexity. The most common indication that a task queue would be useful is the running time - no need to make your web layer spend a lot of time waiting for a cpu intensive task to finish while blocking other requests from being handled.

Comment: And could you also give an opinion about my architecture in the project? Is it correct that each route inherits a specific set of functions with access to the database?

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever you're inheriting from; generally you use `Depends` in FastAPI to provide dependencies to view/controller functions, but there are many different ways to do that - including using class based views through the fastapi cbv module. Code review is generally better suited for the Code Review Stack Exchange site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/